# Free conference CMS

Tags: content-management-system, conference

I need to cms to manage a conference.

What is best free CMS for this?

Comment: You should add some more detailed requirements to get more useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Drupal](http://drupal.org/) is the most flexible open-source CMS that I know. It also has a [Conference module](http://drupal.org/project/conference) that maybe does some  of the things you need. The rest should be possible using Views/CCK (also Drupal modules).

Check out this Article about a [Conference website created with Drupal](http://drupal.org/node/519100), it is probably much more complicated than what you need but it shows what is possible with Drupal.

Comment: thanks but this conference is not online. for conference website i need a cms.

Comment: @chalist Drupal is a CMS that can be (and has been) used for a conference website.

Answer (score 2):

What about Indico?

- http://indico-software.org
- http://github.com/indico/indico

It's mostly targeted at organization of series of conferences, though.

*Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of Indico myself.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have done a few in Drupal. Also see: http://sf2010.drupal.org/ for an excellent example

Answer (score 0):

try this drupal module. 
It seems good
http://usecod.com